# Python test for missing static file

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, exception

I have the following MWE (the actual code is bigger, but this is the part I want to test):

```
def processFile():
  fileToProcess = "localFile.txt"
  try:
    with open(fileToProcess, "rb") as f:
      # Process file here
  except EnvironmentError:
    # Handle Exception
```

My question is:
How can I test the function above, to test whether the exception is thrown or not. My understanding of testing (which is very limited) is, that one is calling the function in a test and causing the "failure" to happen, while asserting.

```
def testProcessFile(self):
  self.assertRaises(???)
```

But how can I invalidate the presence of the file, without actually deleting it? Thanks!

Comment: If the function already handles the exception, the caller will never know whether or not the exception was raised (unless you re-raise or return specific values that tell you what happened).

Comment: Okay, I was expecting an answer like that, thanks! I just wasn't sure if there is a way to manipulate a variable in the actual function from the test (i.e., the variable "fileToProcess")

Answer (score 0):

Just change the path to the file to a directory where you know that file doesn't exists

```
def processFile():
  try:
    with open("fake_dir/localFile.txt", "rb") as f:
      # Process file here
  except EnvironmentError:
      # Handle Exception
```

Comment: Sorry, I think it was unclear, that I wanted to write a test function to test the actual function. I added that in the question.

Comment: Then maybe add a parameter to the function that represent the path of the file, with a default value of 'localFile.txt', this way the function call is unchanged and only when you call the function with the parameter you actually test it.